# tailing file into web page using nodejs and io.socket

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to tail a file into webpage.
I want to do it as efficient that it can be.
I looked into our old friend google , but couldn't decide what to take , and more important - how.
let's say I have a txt file , and every time something is written inside it , I want the new data to be printed on the web page.
I'm Noob on all this web area, so please be kind :)
I tried to look into nodejs and io.socket and couldn't make it work.
if you think of other good and effective solution - please share it with me.
I'll be happy to get some help here.
Please be easy on me ..

Thanks !